# Server-side rendering with ReactDOM.hydrate

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-fiber

`hydrate` has [landed to React 16](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/10339), but its use isn't documented yet.

[This article](https://blog.cloudboost.io/react-16-is-the-first-release-that-ships-with-a-rewrite-of-the-react-core-previously-codenamed-cf37fa00a535) suggests that it is is supposed to be used with `renderToNodeStream` but doesn't give much details.

What is the expected usage of `hydrate`?

`renderToString` is synchronous. It also cannot handle re-rendered  components, i.e. when synchronous (i.e. same tick) changes happen in component state during initial rendering and are supposed to trigger additional `render` calls. The example is Helmet that requires [a workaround](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#as-string-output) in order to propagate changes from nested `Helmet` back to top-level component on server side.

Can `hydrate` and `renderToNodeStream` help to avoid `renderToString` limitations and render asynchronous and/or re-rendered components on server side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hydrate`'s usage is not limited to `renderToNodeStream` - you can (actually should) also use it with the classical `renderToString`. `renderToNodeStream` is essentially the same as `renderToString` with exception that it produces an http stream instead of a string. This means that you can send the rendered html to the client *byte by byte* during rendering, contrary to the standard `renderToString`, when you have to wait for the whole html string to be rendered first, and only after can you send it to the client.

`ReactDOM.hydrate` is a replacement for standard `ReactDOM.render`. The basic (and only?) difference is that, contrary to `ReactDOM.render`, it doesn't throw away all the DOM if React's checksum on the client doesn't match the one calculated on the server. It tries to attach React client app to the server-rendered DOM even if there are some subtle differences, by patching just the differing parts.

Due to the streaming nature of `renderToNodeStream`, Helmet's server-side usage is practically impossible in the current state of the library - the `head` part of the DOM is sent to the server by the time React get's to compute the DOM including Helmet's components. The stream can't just revert and append Helmet's changes to `head`.

So to sum, answering your question - `renderToNodeStream` solves the problem of synchronous rendering to string by sending stream, but it introduces new problem of not being able to patch the pushed content if some further part of the React App requires it. It doesn't add anything in terms of state changing and rerendering on the server side. On the other hand, `hydrate` doesn't introduce anything new in this topic - it's just a tuned up, more forgiving version of the old `render`.

The official docs explain a lot! https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html